# k3s on arch linux ARM worker service not responding

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, archlinux-arm, k3s

Current setup:

```
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION        INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
cl01mtr01   Ready    master   104m    v1.18.2+k3s1   10.1.1.1      <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-9-amd64   containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
cl01wkr01   Ready    <none>   9m20s   v1.18.2+k3s1   10.1.1.101    <none>        Arch Linux ARM                 5.4.40-1-ARCH    containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
```

Master installed with:

```
export INSTALL_K3S_VERSION="v1.18.2+k3s1"
curl -sSLf https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server \
  --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 \
  --cluster-cidr 172.20.0.0/16 \
  --service-cidr 172.21.0.0/16 \
  --cluster-dns 172.21.0.10 \
  --disable traefik
```

Worker installed with:

```
export INSTALL_K3S_VERSION="v1.18.2+k3s1"
curl -sSLf https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - agent \
  --server https://10.1.1.1:6443 \
  --token <token from master>
```

I also tried with a raspberry pi as master running arch linux and raspbian and a rock pi 64 with armbian.

I tried with k3s versions:

- v1.17.4+k3s1
- v1.17.5+k3s1
- v1.18.2+k3s1

I also tested with docker and the `--docker` install option in k3s.

The nodes get discovered (as shown above), but I *cannot* access the service on my worker node(s) (raspberry pi 3 with arch linux arm) via http://10.1.1.1:30001 although, it *can* be accessed via `kubectl exec`.

I always get a connection timeout

```
This site can’t be reached
10.1.1.1 took too long to respond.
```

When the pod runs on the master node, or if the worker is an `amd64` node, it *can* be accessed via http://10.1.1.1:30001.

This is the resource I try to load and access:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-configmap
  namespace: nginx
data:
  default.conf: |
    server {
        listen      80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        #server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      targetPort: 80
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30001
    - name: https
      targetPort: 443
      port: 443
      nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-daemonset
  namespace: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - "true"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:stable
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: "Europe/Brussels"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        volumeMounts:
        - name: default-conf
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          subPath: default.conf
          readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: default-conf
        configMap:
          name: nginx-default-configmap
```

Some extra info:

```
> kubectl get all -A -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   pod/local-path-provisioner-6d59f47c7-d477m   1/1     Running   0          116m   172.20.0.4   cl01mtr01   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-7566d596c8-fbb7b          1/1     Running   0          116m   172.20.0.2   cl01mtr01   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-8655855d6-gnbsm                  1/1     Running   0          116m   172.20.0.3   cl01mtr01   <none>           <none>
nginx         pod/nginx-daemonset-l4j7s                    1/1     Running   0          52s    172.20.1.3   cl01wkr01   <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE     NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE    SELECTOR
default       service/kubernetes       ClusterIP   172.21.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      116m   <none>
kube-system   service/kube-dns         ClusterIP   172.21.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       116m   k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system   service/metrics-server   ClusterIP   172.21.152.234   <none>        443/TCP                      116m   k8s-app=metrics-server
nginx         service/nginx-service    NodePort    172.21.14.185    <none>        80:30001/TCP,443:30002/TCP   52s    app=nginx

NAMESPACE   NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES         SELECTOR
nginx       daemonset.apps/nginx-daemonset   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          52s   nginx        nginx:stable   app=nginx

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE    CONTAINERS               IMAGES                                   SELECTOR
kube-system   deployment.apps/local-path-provisioner   1/1     1            1           116m   local-path-provisioner   rancher/local-path-provisioner:v0.0.11   app=local-path-provisioner
kube-system   deployment.apps/metrics-server           1/1     1            1           116m   metrics-server           rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6            k8s-app=metrics-server
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                  1/1     1            1           116m   coredns                  rancher/coredns-coredns:1.6.3            k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE    CONTAINERS               IMAGES                                   SELECTOR
kube-system   replicaset.apps/local-path-provisioner-6d59f47c7   1         1         1       116m   local-path-provisioner   rancher/local-path-provisioner:v0.0.11   app=local-path-provisioner,pod-template-hash=6d59f47c7
kube-system   replicaset.apps/metrics-server-7566d596c8          1         1         1       116m   metrics-server           rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6            k8s-app=metrics-server,pod-template-hash=7566d596c8
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-8655855d6                  1         1         1       116m   coredns                  rancher/coredns-coredns:1.6.3            k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=8655855d6
```

Comment: How did you try to access the service that running worker node? `kubectl exec` or via browser? What's the error you're getting? @Maarten

Comment: I updated the question. I get a connection timeout via the browser, but a `kubectl exec` works just fine.

Comment: According to your information. Now nginx pod is running on worker node `cl01wkr01`. Which has the IP address of `10.1.1.101`. So, you should try to access the service via `http://10.1.1.101:30001` instead of `http://10.1.1.1:30001`

Comment: When accessing via `http://10.1.1.101:30001` it works. But it's a cluster, I don't want to lookup on what node the pod is running and querying its IP...

Comment: You've to deploy a load balancer on your cluster and create ingress rules with hostname to access your services.

Comment: Why would that entire setup work when using `x86_64` machines and for `arm` not?
I tested it with traefik enabled and ingress rules and the behaviour is exactly the same.